# How do I access "order" in this JSON (with semicolons in the name)?

Tags: javascript, json

[Vijay Anand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6084037/vijay-anand) asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60462077/error-while-reading-a-json-object-with-a-colon-in-the-key)  yesterday, but it was closed before he got an answer:

**HTTP Response:**

```
{
  "entry": {
    "@xml:base": "https://API_PROC_SRV/",
    "@xmlns": "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
    "@xmlns:m": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata",
    "@xmlns:d": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices",
    "id": "https://API_PROC_SRV/A_Order",
    "title": {
      "@type": "text",
      "#text": "A_Order()"
    },
    "updated": "2020-02-29T07:33:28Z",
    "category": {
      "@term": "Type",
      "@scheme": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"
    },
    "link": [],
    "content": {
      "@type": "application/xml",
      "m:properties": {
        "d:Order": "123456789"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Javascript code:**

```
var json = response;
var order = json.object.entry.content['m:properties']['d:Order']; // I intend to read Order no from the below response.
```

**Error (example, jsbin.com):**

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'entry' of undefined
    at null.js:27:25
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-4.1.7.min.js:1:13924
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-4.1.7.min.js:1:10866"
```

Per [JSLint](https://jslint.com/), the response is valid JSON.

`json.object.entry` is obviously wrong ... but

Q: What is the correct Javascript syntax to access the "order" value (named `d:Order`), when `m:properties` and `d:Order` both have semicolons in the name?

PS: I nominated Vijay's original question for re-opening ... but I'm not optimistic.  Hence my new question.

Comment: What you have seems right.

Comment: Not sure what `object` is doing in there. Try `json.entry.content['m:properties']['d:Order']` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the JSON. And there's no `object` property anywhere, it's jut `json.entry.content`.

```js
response = `{
  "entry": {
    "@xml:base": "https://API_PROC_SRV/",
    "@xmlns": "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
    "@xmlns:m": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata",
    "@xmlns:d": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices",
    "id": "https://API_PROC_SRV/A_Order",
    "title": {
      "@type": "text",
      "#text": "A_Order()"
    },
    "updated": "2020-02-29T07:33:28Z",
    "category": {
      "@term": "Type",
      "@scheme": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"
    },
    "link": [],
    "content": {
      "@type": "application/xml",
      "m:properties": {
        "d:Order": "123456789"
      }
    }
  }
}`;
var json = JSON.parse(response);
var order = json.entry.content['m:properties']['d:Order'];
console.log(order);
```